# Nombre de Widget o Clase (con?) variable en Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

Necesito invocar Widgets, muchos Widgets, con nombres tales como S1, S2, S3, y muchos más con características similares (letra+número). Es posible hacer uso de algún método para esto en Flutter?

Necesito hacer algo como:

```
builder: (context) => S'$i'(),     // i es una variable, por ejemplo un contador
```

en vez de:

```
builder: (context) => S1(),
builder: (context) => S2(),
builder: (context) => S3(),
...
```

Agradezco su colaboración.

Comment: no es posible , a menos que uses code generators , pero es en tiempo de compilación no de ejecución , que deseas conseguir con eso ?

Comment: @diegoveloper gracias por tu comentario.  Deseo conseguir eso porque necesito llamar a distintos Widgets con base en ciertos requerimientos, y utilizar números según describo para los nombres sería perfecto.  Ya veré el tema de los code generators, más bien de tipo avanzado.  Saludos

Comment: No necesitas crear nuevos widgets para eso, solo pasale un parámetro con el número que deseas, pero no necesitas que cada widget tengan un nombre diferente